# How to set docker's NO_PROXY with wildcard

Tags: docker, proxy

As mentioned in the official docker docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#configure-where-the-docker-daemon-listens-for-connections), proxy setting for docker can be assigned here /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/https-proxy.conf, like:

```
[Service]    
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com:443/" "NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,docker-registry.somecorporation.com"
```

But, the docker's downloading relates a lot of url redirecting. So I hardly name them one by one in the setting here.

So my question is that is there any methods to achieve wildcard, such as *.docker.io.

Thanks,
Cross

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I understand that this is a question from some years ago, but I guess this is still a common question for developers and I don't feel it's properly answered.

Regarding the approved answer from @Kaneg, effectively a leading `.` will do the trick in the majority of the cases... But not always.

Due to that, I'm writing this answer in case more people ends up in this question in a future.

---

First of all, we have to keep in mind that the famous `NO_PROXY` is an environment variable that the majority of Web Clients accept at the time of using a Web proxy server, but there is no standard about how it has to be defined or how each client should handle these.

When we set up those in Docker as environment variables, we're just forcing all the containers that will be created in the future to use those environment variables and they will be used for Docker as well (for example to download images from the official registry). Anyway, the real deal depends on what do we have inside of those containers, since that's where the requirements will get strict.

In order to simplify this to the maximum, I've taken this table from the [GitLab blog](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/01/27/we-need-to-talk-no-proxy/) (thank you, Stan Hu):

|  | curl | wget | Ruby | Python | Go |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `no_proxy` | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| `NO_PROXY` | Yes | No | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Case precedence | lowercase | lowercase only | lowercase | lowercase | lowercase |
| Matches suffixes? | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Strips leading `.`? | Yes | No | Yes | Yes | No |
| `*` maches all hosts? | Yes | No | No | Yes | Yes |
| Supports regexes? | No | No | No | No | No |
| Supports CIDR blocks? | No | No | Yes | No | Yes |
| Detects loopbacks IPs? | No | No | No | No | Yes |
| Reference | [link](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/30e7641d7d2eb46c0b67c0c495a0ea7e52333ee2/lib/url.c#L2152-L2206) | [link](https://github.com/jay/wget/blob/099d8ee3da3a6eea5635581ae517035165f400a5/src/retr.c#L1266-L1274) | [link](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/0ed71b37fa9af134fdd5a7fd1cebd171eba83541/lib/uri/generic.rb#L1545-L1554) | [link](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/030a713183084594659aefd77b76fe30178e23c8/Lib/urllib/request.py#L2519-L2551) | [link](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/682a1d2176b02337460aeede0ff9e49429525195/src/vendor/golang.org/x/net/http/httpproxy/proxy.go#L170-L206) |

#### What does this mean?

That if we just follow the logic of setting a leading `.` in the `NO_PROXY`, first of all this one won't be understood by tools like `wget`, so they will pass through the Proxy anyway; and in the case that we would set the leading `.` as `no_proxy` still `curl` will always strip the leading `.` meanwhile `wget` won't strip it and will perform an exact string match against the hostname.

#### Solution

Suffixes are ALWAYS matched, so the best solution is to set `docker.io` as it will include `whatever.docker.io`. Try to avoid using a leading dot (`.`) if top-level domains need to be matched in every case.

Answer (score 9):

In NO_PROXY, you can use wildcard to match multiple host with same domain. For *.docker.io, you can use **.docker.io**

Comment: Do you mean "can use wildcards" or "can't use wildcards"?