# How to set up docker with no_proxy settings

Tags: docker, proxy, docker-compose

I'm setting up three docker containers on my own machine using docker compose:

- One is a portal written with React.js (called `portal`)
- One is a middleware layer with GraphQL (called `gateway`)
- One is an auth service with node.js (called `auth`)

I also have a bunch of services already running behind a corporate firewall.

For the most part, `gateway` will request resources behind the firewall, so I have configured docker containers to proxy requests through a squid proxy with access to the additional services. However requests to my local `auth` service, and other local services should not proxied. As such, I have the following docker proxy configuration (note the `noProxy` settings):

```
~/.docker/config.json

    ...
    "proxies": {
        "default": {
            "httpProxy": "http://172.30.245.96:3128",
            "httpsProxy": "http://172.30.245.96:3128",
            "noProxy": "auth,localhost,127.0.0.1,192.168.0.1/24"
        }
    }
    ...
```

With the above setup, `portal` requests **do** go directly to `gateway` through the browser using `http://192.168.0.15/foo`, but when `gateway` makes requests to `auth` using `http://auth:3001/bar`, they **do not** go directly to `auth` but instead **do** go through the proxy - which I am trying to avoid.

I can see the auth request is sent through the proxy with the squid proxy errors:

```
<p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href="http://auth:3001/token">http://auth:3001/bar</a></p>
```

How can I set up the docker containers to respect the `noProxy` setting using docker service names like `auth`? It appears to me that the request from `gateway` to `auth` is mistakingly being proxed through `172.30.245.96:3128`, causing it to not work. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237038/how-to-set-dockers-no-proxy-with-wildcard
CIDR ranges are only supported by Go and Ruby

Answer (score 3):

Your Docker configuration seems fine, but your host doesn't understand how to resolve the name `auth`.  Based on the IP given (192.168.x.x), I'll assume that you're attempting to reach the container service from the host.  Add an entry for `auth` into your host's `/etc/hosts` (`C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` if on Windows).

Take a look at [Linked docker-compose containers making http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987726/linked-docker-compose-containers-making-http-requests) for more details.
If you run into issues reaching services from within the container, check [docker-compose resolve hostname in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55274801/docker-compose-resolve-hostname-in-url) for an example.